# How do I install SOOT?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04, soot

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to install SOOT. Can somebody help me how to do that? Is there any plugin for IntelliJIDEA for this?
Do I have to download the whole source code for this from git hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing and running Soot is as simple as downloading the soot.jar file and executing the following command.

```
Java –jar soot.jar
```

As long as you have your JAVA_HOME variable set correctly it should work fine. Then you should read about how to integrate it with IntelliJIDEA here on [GitHub](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki)

Comment: Yes, found on the github(https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Building-Soot-with-IntelliJ-IDEA). Thanks :)